# PostgreSQL Error: Database Locale Incompatibility Following Windows Update (From Turkish_Turkey.1254 to Turkish_Türkiye.1254)

Tags: database, postgresql, database-connection, windows-update, turkish

I'm encountering an issue while trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database in a Flask web application. I'm getting an error message like "Database connection failed." Upon investigating the source of the problem, I noticed that the language settings in the postgresql.conf file are mismatched. Previously, Turkish_Turkey.1254 language was used when the database was created, but with the latest Windows update, this language is no longer available, and instead, Turkish_Türkiye.1254 is being used.

I've tried updating the language settings in the postgresql.conf file, but the issue persists. I'm unsure of the steps to follow to get the PostgreSQL service running or how to resolve this language incompatibility.

I'm sharing the relevant code snippets and error messages below:
postgresql.conf:

lc_messages = 'Turkish_Türkiye.1254'

lc_monetary = 'Turkish_Türkiye.1254'

lc_numeric = 'Turkish_Türkiye.1254'

lc_time = 'Turkish_Türkiye.1254'

Error Message:
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database locale is incompatible with operating system
DETAIL:  The database was initialized with LC_COLLATE "Turkish_Turkey.1254",  which is not recognized by setlocale().
HINT:  Recreate the database with another locale or install the missing locale.

I've tried updating the language settings in the postgresql.conf file according to the guidance provided by PostgreSQL documentation, but the issue persists. I expected that updating the language settings to match the new system locale would resolve the connection error and allow me to successfully connect to the PostgreSQL database. However, despite these changes, I continue to encounter the same error message.

Comment: This is a reported [Bug](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/18196-b10f93dfbde3d7db%40postgresql.org), though I don't see solution other then a pointer to this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188837/postgresql-9-5-wont-start-after-windows-10-fall-update.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very crude solution; proceed at your own peril. A better solution might be to use [Locale Builder 2.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41158) to create a new locale named `Turkish_Turkey.1254` and install it on the system as prescribed [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188837/postgresql-9-5-wont-start-after-windows-10-fall-update).

First, I verified the behavior I was suspecting using the following C++ program:

```cpp
#include <locale.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    printf("The locale is set to: %s\n", setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish.1254"));
    printf("The locale is set to: %s\n", setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish_Türkiye.1254"));
}
```

I received this output:

```
The locale is set to: Turkish_Türkiye.1254
The locale is set to: Turkish_Türkiye.1254
```

After seeing that `Turkish.1254` and `Turkish_Türkiye.1254` are identical on my server, I took the following steps:

1. Uninstalled the offending update, which was `KB5035857` for me.
2. Connected to the database as a superuser and ran the following SQL statement:

   ```sql
   UPDATE pg_database SET datcollate='Turkish.1254', datctype='Turkish.1254'
   ```
3. Reinstalled the update.
4. Ran following sql statement:

   ```sql
   UPDATE pg_database SET datcollate='Turkish_Türkiye.1254', datctype='Turkish_Türkiye.1254'
   ```